# unhandled exception?? tiny error of if statement i cant seem to fix

Tags: visual-c++

so this project requires an input of U, M, or D and as many as you like of them (i think, might be only up to 100 based on charUMD[100] array in code) also, you have to end it with # in order to indicate the end. i am trying to say that if you dont include #, then program should cout the error message Error: String Does Not End With '#'! as seen in if statement in main. however, it gives me unhandled exception error because of "out of range". how can i fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int length;

char UMD[100];
char value;
int i = 0;
string list;

void SWAP(char s[], int i, int j)
{
    char x, y;
    x = s[i];
    y = s[j];
    s[j] = x;
    s[i] = y;
}

void sort(char s[])
{
    for (int c = 0; c < (i - 1); c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < i - c - 1; d++)
        {
            if (UMD[d] <= UMD[d + 1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
            {
                SWAP(UMD, d, (d + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
        cout << "TYPE U, M, or D for the array" << endl;
        cout << "Type any other letter to stop adding!" << endl;

        cin >> list;
        int o = 0;
        while (list[o] != 0)
        {
            i++;
            o++;
        }

        int p = 0;
        while ((list.at(p)) != '#')
        {
            UMD[p] = list.at(p); p++;
        }

        if (UMD[o] != '#'){ cout << "Error: String Does Not End With '#'!" << endl; system("pause"); exit(0); }//<------IF UMD[o] is not '#', then it should display this message! However it does not work for '#' IDK WHY!

        for (int z = 0; z < p; z++)
        {
            if (list.at(z) != 'U'&&list.at(z) != 'M'&&list.at(z) != 'D')
            {
                cout << "Error: character other than U, M, or D provided" << endl; system("pause"); exit(0);
                cout << list.at(z);
            }
        }

        sort(UMD);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Here is the sorted version of the array" << endl;
        for (int z = 0; z < i; z++)
        {
            cout << UMD[z];
        }

        cin >> list;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You first run a loop that relies on `#` being present, and only then attempt to check whether it is indeed present. Besides, the condition `UMD[o] != '#'` is always true: after all, we know that `list[o] == 0` (or we wouldn't have gotten out of the very first loop), and contents of `UMD` would be the copy of the contents of `list` if the second loop actually worked.

Comment: `std::string` knows its own length, accessible via `list.length()` or `list.size()` (the two are synonyms). All this hunting for terminating characters is misguided, whether it be `0` or `#`.

Comment: so...how do i fix this to reflect my need?

Comment: Something along these lines: `cin >> list; size_t p = list.find_first_not_of("UMD"); if (p != string::npos) { /* non-UMD character found at index p */ }`